# Flutter - Amplify Graphql - Type "Null" is not a subtype of "String" - RESOLVED!! Explanation at the end

Tags: flutter, dart, graphql, flutter-aws-amplify

I'm getting an error that says `type "Null" is not a subtype of "String". I have no idea where this error is coming from. I can't understand, because It works just fine in amplify studio and it works just fine in AppSync. I'm out of options. Please help! :)
I know that I don't have to write graphql query to get a list of activities. But this is the only way to get activityMessages data  together because I have a 1:many relationship

For testing, I set a breakpoint where it says `final test = await res.response`.

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tezV.png)

Debugger screenshot

[image: debug_img]

AppSync screenshot

[image: AppSync screenshot]

Amplify Studio screenshot

[image: Amplify Studio screenshot]

It doesn't get to the `return`

This is my code that throws me an error

```dart
   Future<Request<List<Activity?>>> fetchActivitiesByDay(TemporalDate day, String schoolID) async {
    try {
      const listActivities = 'listActivities';
      const graphQLDocument = '''query MyQuery {
  listActivities {
    items {
      id
    end_time
    description
    title
    }
  }
};
      final getPostRequest = GraphQLRequest<Activity>(
        document: graphQLDocument,
        modelType: Activity.classType,
        // variables: <String, String>{'id': 'b34f6dfc-fb18-4f20-85cf-57e97671d480'},
        decodePath: listActivities,
      );
      final res = Amplify.API.query(request: getPostRequest);
      final test = await res.response;
      return formatRequestList<Activity?>(test);
    } on ApiException catch (e) {
      throw e.message;
    }
  }
```

I've tried without providing a query

```
const graphQLDocument = '''query {
  listActivities {
    items {
      id
    end_time
    description
    title
    }
  }
};
```

If I try to get a single activity it works just fine.

```
const graphQLDocument = '''query GetActivity(\$id: ID!) {
  getActivity(id: \$id) {
    id
  }
};
```

This is how my schema looks like

```
type Activity
  @model
  @auth(
    rules: [{ allow: private, operations: [read, update] }, { allow: owner }]
  ) {
  id: ID!
  schoolID: ID!
  category: ActivityEnum!
  title: String!
  start_time: AWSTime!
  end_time: AWSTime!
  date: AWSDate!
  description: String!
  activityMessages: [ActivityMessage]
    @hasMany(indexName: "byActivity", fields: ["id"])
}

type ActivityMessage
  @model
  @auth(rules: [{ allow: private, operations: [read] }, { allow: owner }]) {
  id: ID!
  schoolID: ID!
  activityID: ID! @index(name: "byActivity", sortKeyFields: ["message"])
  activity: Activity! @belongsTo(fields: ["activityID"])
  message: String
  isImage: Boolean!
  imageKey: String
  url: String
  likes: Int!
  createdAt: AWSDateTime
  updatedAt: AWSDateTime
}
```

EXPLANATION!!
The problem was that `modelType: Activity.classType` is to get single instance. To get a list I had to use `modelType: const PaginatedModelType(Activity.classType)` and this solved my problem.
[Working Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gf8z0.png)

Comment: instead of `!` you can use ` ?? ''` to set a default value if the return value is `null`. By that, I think your problem will be solved.

Comment: Where should I use that?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this change will solve your issue:

```dart
const graphQLDocument = '''query MyQuery {
  listActivities {
    items {
      id
      end_time
      description
      title
      activityMessages {
        items {
          id
          message
          isImage
          imageKey
          url
          likes
        }
      }
    }
  }
}''';
```

Comment: It didn't work. I still get the same error :/

Comment: Omg.. I solved it :) it works now. I was providing wrong model type. `modelType: Activity.classType` is for a single instance. To get a list I had to use `modelType: const PaginatedModelType(Activity.classType)`